# How to dynamically pass hostname to kickstart file with cobbler

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, kickstart, cobbler

In the kickstart file you can set the hostname like this:

```
network  --hostname=derp.fart
```

I can create a new system with this command

```
cobbler system add --name=MYNEWSYSTEM --profile=string --mac=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

How Can I have cobbler put the name of the system (MYNEWSYSTEM) in for the --hostname param in the kickstart file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cobbler uses Cheetah as the templating engine and according to [the documentation](http://cobbler.github.io/manuals/2.8.0/3/5_-_Kickstart_Templating.html), `$hostname` is a built-in variable that you can use.

You can see other variables with;

```
cobbler system dumpvars --name=system
```